# Can't create table foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: sql

I already checked other answers but nothing solves my particular problem. Maybe I can't understand them, I'm new to all this. I'll leave the code here:

```
CREATE TABLE ciudades 
(
    IDCIUDAD decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPCION varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (IDCIUDAD)
);

INSERT INTO ciudades VALUES (1,'Alcorcón');
INSERT INTO ciudades VALUES (2,'Getafe');
INSERT INTO ciudades VALUES (3,'Madrid');
INSERT INTO ciudades VALUES (4,'Móstoles');

CREATE TABLE especialidades 
(
    IDESPECIALIDAD decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPCION varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE citas 
(
    IDCITA decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
    FECHA datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    IDMEDICO varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    IDPACIENTE decimal(11,0) DEFAULT NULL,
    HABITACION decimal(11,0) DEFAULT NULL,
    CAMA varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    PAGO decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE medicos 
(
    IDMEDICO varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    APELLIDOS varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    NOMBRE varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    IDESPECIALIDAD decimal(11,0) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (IDMEDICO),
    KEY FK_MED_ESP (IDESPECIALIDAD),
    CONSTRAINT FK_MED_ESP 
        FOREIGN KEY (IDESPECIALIDAD) REFERENCES especialidades (IDESPECIALIDAD)
);

CREATE TABLE pacientes 
(
    IDPACIENTE decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
    APELLIDOS varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    NOMBRE varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    FECHA_NACIMIENTO datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    DIRECCION varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    TELEFONO varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    IDCIUDAD decimal(11,0) DEFAULT NULL,
);
```

The line:

```
CONSTRAINT FK_MED_ESP FOREIGN KEY (IDESPECIALIDAD) REFERENCES especialidades (IDESPECIALIDAD)
```

is the one causing the "ERROR 1005: Can't create table (errno: 150)". I already tried changing `IDESPECIALIDAD` to `NOT NULL`. Please, somebody point me in the right direction. I've lost many hours trying to figure this out and I bet it's a simple solution, but I'm way to new to this to find it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *giving me errors* is useless without the **complete, exact error message** that you're getting. Please [edit] your post to provide the necessary information. Also, you'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works.

Answer (score 0):

The table `especialidades` doesn't have a primary key.  Instead define it as:

```
CREATE TABLE especialidades (
  IDESPECIALIDAD decimal(11,0) PRIMARY KEY,
  DESCRIPCION varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

`PRIMARY KEY` means that the value is `NOT NULL`, so there is no reason to include that in the definition as well (it would be redundant).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gordon. There were many more mistakes, but you pointed one that I was ignoring.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so, I finally learned what the problems were. As Gordon Linoff mentioned, I needed to add primary keys to some tables, also the foreign keys. I also had to change the data types of some keys so they would match. And finally, just re-order the code so that the tables are created in the correct order. Here's the working code:

```
CREATE TABLE ciudades (
  IDCIUDAD decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPCION varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (IDCIUDAD)
);

INSERT INTO ciudades VALUES (1,'Alcorcón');
INSERT INTO ciudades VALUES (2,'Getafe');
INSERT INTO ciudades VALUES (3,'Madrid');
INSERT INTO ciudades VALUES (4,'Móstoles');

CREATE TABLE especialidades (
  IDESPECIALIDAD decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPCION varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (IDESPECIALIDAD)
);

CREATE TABLE medicos (
  IDMEDICO varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  APELLIDOS varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  NOMBRE varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  IDESPECIALIDAD decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (IDMEDICO),
  KEY FK_MED_ESP (IDESPECIALIDAD),
  CONSTRAINT FK_MED_ESP FOREIGN KEY (IDESPECIALIDAD) REFERENCES especialidades (IDESPECIALIDAD)
);


CREATE TABLE pacientes (
    IDPACIENTE decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
    APELLIDOS VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    NOMBRE VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    FECHA_NACIMIENTO DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    DIRECCION VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    TELEFONO VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    IDCIUDAD decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (IDPACIENTE),
    KEY FK_PAC_CIU (IDCIUDAD),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PAC_CIU FOREIGN KEY (IDCIUDAD) REFERENCES ciudades (IDCIUDAD)
);


CREATE TABLE citas (
  IDCITA decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
  FECHA datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  IDMEDICO varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  IDPACIENTE decimal(11,0) NOT NULL,
  HABITACION decimal(11,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  CAMA varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PAGO decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (IDCITA),
  KEY FK_CIT_MED (IDMEDICO),
  CONSTRAINT FK_CIT_MED FOREIGN KEY (IDMEDICO) REFERENCES medicos (IDMEDICO),
  KEY FK_CIT_PAC (IDPACIENTE),
  CONSTRAINT FK_CIT_PAC FOREIGN KEY (IDPACIENTE) REFERENCES pacientes (IDPACIENTE)
  );
```